# Different Chrome console output for the same code with different versions of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following js code:

```
var T = function(){};
var tw = new T();
T.prototype.toString = function(){return "1";};

Object.prototype.findOwnerOfProperty = function(propName){
    var currentObject = this;
    while(currentObject !== null){
        if(currentObject.hasOwnProperty(propName)){
            return currentObject;
        } else {
            currentObject = currentObject.__proto__;
        }
    }
    return "No property found!";
};

console.log(tw.findOwnerOfProperty("toString"));
```

Firstly I ran it on Chrome 27.0.1453.110 with a JavaScript engine V8 3.17.6.15. The output is:

```
Object {toString: function, findOwnerOfProperty: function}
```

Then I ran it on Chrome 40.0.2214.111 with a JavaScript engine V8 3.30.33.16. The output is:

```
T {toString: function, findOwnerOfProperty: function}
```

Does anyone know why the outputs are different?

Comment: Must be Chrome now shows the name of the constructor for custom objects in the console. Is there a specific problem this is causing?

Comment: No specific problem... I just feel very wired and want to know the reason.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? The console logs objects differently across the two versions. It now tells you the name of the object, instead of just `Object`